# Building a bidirectional LSTM model

Tags: python

Can someone please help me with my code. I'm trying to build a bidirectional LSTM model predicting the next two words following a sequence of words. I'm using a Project Gutenberg text. Also new to python. Any help is appreciated!!!

This is my code for the input and output sequences for the BiLSTM model:

MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 15

```
def prepare_sequences(words, unk_index, seqlen=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH):
  trunc_length = len(words) % seqlen
  X = np.array(words)[trunc_length:].reshape((-1, seqlen))
  y = np.array(words + [unk_index])[trunc_length + 2:].reshape((-1, seqlen))
  return X, y

Xtrain, ytrain = prepare_sequences(train_indices, word_to_index["<UNK>"])
Xtest, ytest = prepare_sequences(test_indices, word_to_index["<UNK>"])

#Inspect
print(Xtrain.shape, ytrain.shape)
print(Xtest.shape, ytest.shape)
```

Right now, the output (y) is only shifted by 1 word (ie, predict the next word). But how do I alter this code so that the output (y) is shifted by two words?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks. I've altered my question.

Comment: MREs have sample data and expected results.